# Pandas merge two series to a dataframe jointly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want merge two series effectively, `S1 = pd.Series(["A", "B"])` and `S2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])`.

Result dataframe is like below:

```
    S1  S2
 0  A   1
 1  A   2
 2  A   3
 3  B   1
 4  B   2
 5  B   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
df = S1.to_frame(name='S1').merge(S2.to_frame(name='S2'), how='cross')
```

OUTPUT:

```
  S1  S2
0  A   1
1  A   2
2  A   3
3  B   1
4  B   2
5  B   3
```